# Laravel 9 - Dompdf generates broken content

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

i'm working on my laravel project and im using dompdf library.
Everything was working fine and suddenly on a new generation all the content is split by single row for every letter like in the screen:

[generated pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duVyB.png)

Anybody had this issue?
I already tried to clear all cache of the browser and application

I did not run any composer command.

Inside the export function:

```
$data_grid = OrderGridJde::find($id);
$data_details = OrderDetailJde::where('order_jde_id', $id)->get();
$doc_name = 'preventivo_' . $data_grid->id . '.pdf';
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdfview', compact('data_grid', 'data_details', 'id_agente'));
```

P.S. I have this problem only in local.
Same code is working fine on Stage and Production.

Comment: any code to show?

Comment: You'll be very lucky to find anyone here with the same problem, who also knows a solution. However, if you let everybody here reproduce your problem, by providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there will be reasonable chance that somebody knows why it occurs.

Comment: I found the issue.. the problem was not in the code. I am usinga cdn for bootstrap 4 in the pdf generation. I had to ask the sysadmin to add it to whitelist. After that everything was fine

Answer (score 0):

dompdf sometimes creates errors if you run it over and over again. I have seen similar problems.

If you run it again (maybe new filename) it my work. Not really a good solution but maybe it helps.

Comment: i tried to change the name but nothing... it is working fine on stage and production environment, i have this problem only in local

Comment: i just noticed that it's not rendering properly an image.. There is an image .png with a logo inside and for any reason it's not rendering